# How to track system's clock?

Tags: android

Situation: 
I need to create a program that shows current date and updates some date(that is NOT CURRENT date,it is past date) according to current time(for example after 23:59,date refreshs). In other words,it is simple application,that shows date in the past and time.

What did I try? 
I have found `TextClock` for this. It can show current time,but I cannot track over it.

So what can I do? I need to create my own clock class or use `Timer` and `TimerTask`? Do I need a `Service`?

Answer (score 1):

I think, if I understand you correctly, you're on the right path.  I wasn't familiar that there was even a TextClock view, but it looks pretty basic and will just work for displaying the current time.

Instead, maybe use a TimerTask to update the UI every second, or so, and set one TextView with the current time and another with your other time that's an offset of the [current time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) (current = new Calendar(); current.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); )

You could use [TimerTask](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/), and that'd be pretty easy compared to rolling your own thread or using an AsyncTask.  Get the current time, set it to one text view, manipulate that time variable and set it to the other text view.